# How can I join a table on two fields and retrieve a single column from both matching results?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that look like this:

**Table1**

> ID, TS, Symbol, CurrencyLeft(FK Table2 Currency), CurrencyRight(FK Table2 Currency), FeePercentage

**Table2**

> ID, TS, Currency, CurrencyName

How can I make a single query to retrieve `CurrencyLeft`, `CurrencyRight`, `FeePercentage`, `CurrencyLeftName`, and `CurrencyRightName`, where `CurrencyLeftName` is the `CurrencyName` of `CurrencyLeft` and `CurrencyRightName` is the `CurrencyName` of `CurrencyRight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to add `JOIN` statements each time you want to join a table, just make sure you keep your relationships in order. For example, to do currency left:

```
SELECT m1.currencyLeft, m1.currencyRight, m1.feePercentage, m2.currencyName AS currencyLeftName
FROM table1 m1
JOIN table2 m2 ON m2.currency = m1.currencyLeft;
```

If you want to add in currencyRight, just join `table2` again:

```
SELECT m1.currencyLeft, m1.currencyRight, m1.feePercentage, m2.currencyName AS currencyLeftName, m3.currencyName AS currencyRightName
FROM table1 m1
JOIN table2 m2 ON m2.currency = m1.currencyLeft
JOIN table2 m3 ON m3.currency = m1.currencyRight;
```

Comment: Will this work even though both currencies I would like the name of are in the same table (table2)?

Comment: @HNA As long as you are properly aliasing your tables (like I uesd m1, m2, m3) it should be fine, since you're specifying which table you're looking at. I'm sorry, mine should say `table2` on the last line I will edit.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I accepted your answer since it works! :)

Comment: @HNA glad I could help. :)

Comment: I think you meant the last line to be JOIN table2 m3 ON m3.currency = m1.currencyRight?

Comment: @HNA yes, sorry, I made a typo once again.